# Where does "Update measurements" put its updated measurements? (MeemsTools)

Tags: mapwindow, measurements

I have several .shp files loaded into [MapWindows GIS](http://www.mapwindow.org/).  I go to plug-ins > Meems Tools and click on "UpdateMeasurement Plugin", and it loads.  I click on the Update measurements, and in the the Update measurements window that appears, I click the "Update measurements" button, without changing any of the options in the window.  The "select attribute" section grays out, and the bottom of the window lists "Finished updating measurement values", next to the "MapWindow Wiki help" link.

> Where does it put these updated measurement values?

possibly relevant information:

I'm using Windows 7 version 6.1 .

The files are loaded as multiple layers in the same window of MapWindow GIS.

The files are simplifications using MapShaper.org of the "district" files from "Boundary" on http://hawaii.wr.usgs.gov/maui/data.html .